# Forward all traffic from one IP address through OpenVPN

Tags: iptables, routing, openvpn

What I have...  A virtual machine with two IP addresses, call 'em 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 as eth0 and eth0:1.  It's running OpenVPN now and works fine doing normal stuff using just eth0.

What I want...  Use the second IP address at eth0:1 for all VPN traffic in and out, and route all TCP, UDP and hopefully even ICMP packets through the VPN to the protected host on the inside at 10.8.0.10.  So basically anything directed at 1.1.1.2 instead goes to 10.8.0.10.

Sounds easy.  But I'm getting kinda nowhere.  Packet forwarding isn't wanting to work for me, and routing isn't working (while I can get inbound traffic to come in on 1.1.1.2--duh, that's trivial--I can't get it to use 1.1.1.2 outbound).

Hints?  Pointers to "RTFM" (better than "here's the OpenVPN doc and here's the iptable doc and here's the route command")?

Comment: OpenVPN on this machine runs as client?

Comment: No, OpenVPN is running as a server.  So we have TheInternet<->OpenVPN<->TheInternet<->PC   Basically I'm just sorta wanting the PC to take over the OpenVPN server's second Ethernet address.  And then later add a third IP address and dedicate that to another remote PC.  It's an effort to compartmentalize traffic and allow all the ports to seamlessly pass through.

Comment: Clarifying further, imagine you want to run a web server on 3 machines on the internal network, and present them to the outside world, all listening on the standard ports.  So I want port 80 and 443 for 1.1.1.2 to go to 10.8.0.10.  On the next virtual interface, I want port 80 and 443 for 1.1.1.3 going to 10.8.0.11.  And 1.1.1.4 sending to 10.8.0.12.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your right, you want to have such network design:

```
eth0 - 1.1.1.1
eth0:1 - 1.1.1.2
eth0:2 - 1.1.1.3
eth0:3 - 1.1.1.4
```

Then all traffic that come to 1.1.1.2 you want route to 10.8.0.10 and so on.

If you don't have problems with OpenVPN, then you should use NAT! Your rules for one address should look like this one in `nat` section:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10:80
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.10:443
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MASQUERADE
```

And for sure, you should enable forwarding in your `sysctl` setting.